# Shallow clone with JGIT

Tags: java, git, shallow-copy, jgit

How I can do

```
git clone --depth 1 ...
```

with JGIT library?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't, JGit doesn't yet support shallow clones on the [client side](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475615) (it does on the [server side](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=301627), though).

Comment: this bug indicates that this is available now. Is it the case? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=301627

Comment: Anyone found a way to do this?

Comment: Hmm, Jgit still doesn't support shallow clone as of this post. If you're like me and wondered how the Jenkins plugin offers a shallow option, then you also wouldn't be surprised to hear that those guys implemented an abstraction that *falls back* to jgit when linus git isn't available. I don't know how to use this outside of jenkins but here's the part with the abstraction: https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gitclient/CloneCommand.java.

Comment: To clarify @maxmelbin 's comment: the mentioned bug is about the server implementation inside JGit, the server now supports shallow fetch if requested (see comment #13). `git clone --depth` however is **not** implemented yet, see [bug 475615: Support "git clone --depth" in CloneCommand](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475615)

Comment: There is a WIP implementation of this [on GitHub](https://github.com/timeraider4u/jgit/tree/depth).

Comment: @sdgfsdh do you have an example?

Comment: By now https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475615 has been resolved and JGit 6.3.0 does support shallow clones / fetches on the client side.

Comment: Some 11 years after the question was originally posed, it looks like an implementation now exists, in the (as yet unreleased) 6.5.  Here's the PR: https://git.eclipse.org/r/c/jgit/jgit/+/196477

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Release notes for version 6.5.0](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.jgit/releases/6.5.0/), this has been released on March 15, 2023.

You can now use any of

- `.setDepth(Integer)`
- `.setShallowSince(Instant)`
- `.setShallowSince(OffsetDateTime)`

for example like so:

```java
Git.cloneRepository().setDepth(1)
```