# Jgit Shallow Clone (depth -2)

Tags: java, git, jgit

After a few changes in JGIT(BasePackFetchConnection class) we were able to send command (deepen 2) to the server for shallow clone. 
However when the server responds with a shallow commit Jgit is not able to handle this.

What further commands have to be sent to the server to receive the shallow repository in a pack ?
The below document is not clear regarding how to handle a shallow response
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/pack-protocol.txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shallow clone with JGIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475263/shallow-clone-with-jgit)