# Why is a JGit shallow clone not faster than a full clone?

Tags: git, jgit

I have a fairly large Git repository, where "large" refers to both the history size and the file size. I want to clone this repository from my Java application. I am not interested in the full repository history, I just want the code.

On the command line, `git clone` for this repository takes about 7 minutes, and doing a shallow clone with `git clone --depth 1` takes 12 seconds.

I therefore want to do the same using JGit. However, in JGit both the normal clone and the shallow clone [using the option from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475263/shallow-clone-with-jgit) both take the full 7 minutes.

Am I correct that JGit can't do a "real" shallow clone and instead emulates this somehow? Of if I'm wrong, is it actually possible to do a shallow clone that is faster than a full clone? I would imagine that *faster* is the number 1 reason why people want to do shallow clones in the first place.